# Signature does not match:: IXCBA Inline Checkout By Amazon Magnento Extension

Tags: php, javascript, magento, amazon-web-services, xmlhttprequest

I am using [IXCBA](http://ixcba.com/index.php/magento.html)'s Inline Checkout by Amazon plugin for a Magento store. I have a secure encrypted connection to Amazon using SSL. Every time I am trying to make a purchase I keep on getting the same error:

```
<pre>Simple XMLElement Object
(
Error => SimpleXMLElement Object
Type = > Sender
Code = > SignatureDoesNotMatch
Message = > The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
)

RequestID => id-name
)
<pre/>
```

I checked the AWS secret key and other data and replaced them countless times, but had no luck. I also asked the extension author for help and posted a question at the [Seller Central of Amazon](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=2522198#2522198), but no clues given yet how to solve the issue.

Amazon recommends [some scripts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html) including a JavaScript to check out issues with the signature.

I was considering using this JavaScript:

```
function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {

   var kDate= Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, dateStamp, "AWS4" + key, { asBytes: true})
   var kRegion= Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, regionName, kDate, { asBytes: true });
   var kService=Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, serviceName, kRegion, { asBytes: true });
   var kSigning= Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, "aws4_request", kService, { asBytes: true });

   return kSigning;
}
```

as I at least have some basic knowledge of JavaScript using libraries like jQuery.

But I wonder now what data I need to replace to make the test. I also wonder if I can just use the Firebug JScript console to run the test or if I need to do it differently. The latter I can figure out by testing, but with the former I could use some help.

#### Update

I ran the script in FF Scratchpad and saw the key was missing so I added the AWS Access Key ID and ran it again, but nothing happened. I got no errors nor output.

#### Update II

I got another error when I replaced the access key secret key and merchant ID:

> Important Message
>
> ```
> We're sorry, but there's a problem processing the order from this website.
> Please contact the seller for help on placing this order.
> ```

perhaps the config at Seller Central is not OK? Link is https://payments-sandbox.amazon.com/gp/cba/v2/widgets ... Perhaps wrong version?

The changes in the database do seem like they helped so perhaps the data I entered in the backend was not stored properly by IXCBA.

#### Update III

Code in backend was OK after all. After changing it the code got all mangled so I had to do it from the Magento backend again. But then I got the same XML error. Amazon mentioned this:

> This now looks really strange. To complete an order, there are several
> API calls that your website will have to make. 2 basic ones are
> setPurchaseItems to put the order data into the order, and
> completePurchaseContract to process the order. In your case, the
> signature error is returned by the completePurchaseContract but the
> setPurchaseItems worked fine.
>
> In this case, as long as you made sure that the merchantID, Access Key
> and secret key field doesn't have leading/trailing spaces in your
> magento backend, you will have to reach support from magiex your
> plugin provider to take a look. We don't have access to the code thus
> can't really help you to fix it.

So I contacted [MageIx](https://mageix.com/) again. Waiting for a response while I try to figure things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end there were three issues. One, the installation was somehow not done properly. I had to get it redone. Two, the AWS Merchant ID, key and secret key were not added properly. That I adjusted. And three, there was a server stamp issue that caused and issue with the self signing of the cart. The MageIx developers made a custom extension to circumvent the timestamp issue. Other issues with the entering of the keys and re-installation were not hard to solve. CBA works now

**NB**
The only issue now is that Inline Checkout by Amazon does not seem to work with FBA. But at Amazon half of the devs say it does and the others say it doesn't. But this is an issue for another thread.